# Complexity of recursive function that calls itself with it's own return value

Tags: time-complexity, recursion, big-o-notation

Given the following code:

```
int f3(int n)
{
   if(n <= 2) return 1;
   f3(1 + f3(n-2));
   return n - 1;
}
```

I was trying to find the time complexity and I got this expression: $T(n)=1+T(T(n-2))$ which I've never seen before.

I know the answer is $O(2^{\frac{n}{2}})$ but I have no idea how to get there. Can anyone explain the calculation process?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The correct recurrence is

$$T(n)=T(1+f_3(n-2))+T(n-2),\\T_0=T_1=1.$$

That should be easier to solve.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I was trying to work it from here, but I keep getting the same wrong answer ($O(\frac{n}{2})$). I think that the problem is that I've never seen this type of recursion. If you could give some more explanation it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @complexity: who told you that this answer is wrong ? The solution is virtually in front of your eyes, please read again.

Comment: This problem is taken from a previous test at my university, and the official answer there is $O(2^{\frac{n}{2}})$, and when I try to calculate myself I get $O(\frac{n}{2})=O(n)$. So it is either I'm missing something, or one of the answers is wrong

Comment: @complexity: how to you get this $O$ answer ?